# How to remove a double slash in ruby with URI method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

how to remove a double slash `//` in ruby with URI method?

```
2.4.1 :001 > URI('http://www.rbc.ru/society/23/11/2017/5a16ff0e9a7947e46d1e4957').tap { |uri| uri.query = nil; uri.scheme = nil }.to_s
 => "//www.rbc.ru/society/23/11/2017/5a16ff0e9a7947e46d1e4957"
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan `www.rbc.ru/society/23/11/2017/5a16ff0e9a7947e46d1e4957`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just snip it off:

```
URI('...').to_s.sub(%r[\A//], '')
```

Doesn't have to be that complicated.

Comment: @Stefan In the original question the `scheme` was set to an empty string so the `http:` part is already stripped. See the second line of the question's code.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that your code was supposed to be an alternative to the OP's `tap` block (_"Doesn't have to be that complicated"_).